# How to mock static methods with more than one argument

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

I'm writing a test case to test a component that invokes a static method accepting 5 arguments. I want to know how I can do that.

Earlier I have been successful in mocking static method with 0 and 1 arguments. However when I mock a static method with more than 1 argument, it returns null. Following is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do. The static method has 2 arguments.

```
public interface VO {

}
```

```
public class A implements VO {
    private int value = 5;

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

```
public class Factory {
    public static VO getObj(String a, String b) {
        return new A();
    }
}
```

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({com.csc.fsg.nba.vo.Factory.class})
public class APITest {


    @BeforeClass
    public static void runOnceBeforeClass() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Executing runOnceBeforeClass()");
        A a = new A();
        a.setValue(3);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Factory.class);
        Mockito.when(Factory.getObj(Mockito.any(String.class), Mockito.any(String.class))).thenReturn(a);
    }

    @Test
    public void testA() throws Exception {
        VO vo = Factory.getObj("a", null);
        System.out.println(((A)vo).getValue());
    }

}
```

I'm expecting that sysout should print 3, however vo is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case the `any(String.class)` fails to match the `null` passed when exercising the test

```
//...

VO vo = Factory.getObj("a", null);

//...
```

Use `anyString()`

```
//...

when(Factory.getObj(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(a);
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you! I tried (String)Mockito.any() as my actual code would have custom objects.

Comment: @Nkosi: anyString() does not match `null` - it behaves identical to `any(Sting.class)`. Also `when(Factory.getObj(anyString(), null))` is invalid as you can not use matchers and non-matchers together.